# Birt Viewer View Sertvlet Source Code

Tags: java, report, birt

I would like to integrate birt report viwer into my application. For that I need to customize viewer servlet source. Could anybody please help me in getting the **ViwerServlet Source code?**

Answer (score 2):

This wiki page covers most of the building options:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Birt_Project#Q:_How_do_I_build_BIRT.3F